# Can we set price different for the first year and onward? Like, for first year 2.99 and then 0.99Subscription

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Can we set price different for the first year and onward? Like, for first year 2.99 and then 0.99

Comment: Not with auto-renewing subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! You can set up a Pay-up-Front Introductory price: [SKProductDiscountPaymentModePayUpFront](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductdiscountpaymentmode/skproductdiscountpaymentmodepayupfront?language=objc)

This is set up completely in App Store Connect when configuring your product.

See more about the different types of introductory prices: [iOS Introductory Prices](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-introductory-prices-f1efb4f1a6a2)

Answer (score 0):

There might not be an out of the box solution for this.

But maybe you can try something like this.

1. Create 2 price points 2.99/year and .99/year
2. When the user opens the page, check to see if they've previously bought a subscription, if they have, hide the 2.99/year and show the .99/year
3. If they haven't bought previously, then only show 2.99/year and on a successful purchase, keep a record of it on your backend server.